# docker-compose up: OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu

I am using `docker-compose up` to run a python file, however, there is error info:

```
matching_server_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
matching_server_1  |   File "server.py", line 65, in <module>
matching_server_1  |     server = TCPServer((HOST, PORT), RequestHandler)
matching_server_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
matching_server_1  |     self.server_bind()
matching_server_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
matching_server_1  |     self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
matching_server_1  | OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

But the program runs well by `python3 server.py` without docker.

The structure of the project is:

```
root
   |—docker-compose.yml
   |—matching_engine
         |—Dockerfile
         |-server.py (main)
         |-.......
```

and my Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src
ADD requirements.txt /src/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /src/
```

and my docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: passw0rd
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: EXCHANGEMACHINE
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/data-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
  matching_server:
    build: ./matching_engine
    user: nobody
    command: bash -c "python3 server.py"
    volumes:
      - ./matching_engine:/src
    ports:
      - "12345:12345"
    expose:
      - "12345"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

and the code that reports error in `server.py` is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = '0.0.0.0'
    PORT = 12345
    server = TCPServer((HOST, PORT), RequestHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

What is going wrong in this situation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in your matching_server service

```
links: 
  - db
```

and remove expose: "12345"